# How do I call a function and use its result?

Tags: c, prototype

I have to use prototype poly float to compute `f(x)=5x^2+12.55x+0.75`. I have error every time I run this code because poly is not used. Any help will be good and any tips for prototypes too.

```
#include<stdio.h>
float poly(float x)
{
return 1;
}
int main()
{
float b, c, a;      
printf("Podaj x=");
a = scanf("%f", &b);
c = 5 * b * b + 12.55 * b + 0.75;
if(a<1)
{
    printf("Incorrect input");
    return 1;
}else
{   
printf("Wynik: %.2f", c);
return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why did you define this `poly` function when you then never use it? I guess this excercise is ment that you write a function that evaluates a polynomial at a value `x`.

Comment: So how can i use it?

Comment: This code solve the problem. Thank you very much Eric Postpischil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `poly` to:

```
float poly(float x)
{
    return 5*x*x + 12.55*x + .75;
}
```

In main, you can use the function:

```
print("poly(%g) = %g.\n", b, poly(b));
```